# Simulation of Modelsim launching from Quartus doesn't work properly

Tags: verilog, modelsim, quartus, test-bench

This is the test bench

```
`timescale 1 ps/ 1 ps

module sum_fix_vlg_tst();

reg select;
reg [7:-8] valor_a;
reg [7:-8] valor_b;


// wires                                               
wire [8:-8]  result_fx;

sum_fix i1 (

.result_fx(result_fx),
.select(select),
.valor_a(valor_a),
.valor_b(valor_b)
 );

initial                                                
$monitor ("valor_a = %b, valor_b = %b, result_fx = %b", valor_a, 
valor_b,result_fx);

initial
begin                                                  
#10
select = 1;
valor_a = 32'b0000000011111111;
valor_b = 32'b0000000011111111;

#20

valor_a = 32'b1111111111111111;
valor_b = 32'b1111111111111111;

#30

valor_a = 32'b1001100111001000;
valor_b = 32'b0001111000111101;

end                                                    

endmodule
```

And this is the uut

```
`timescale 1 ps/ 1 ps
module sum_fix (valor_a,valor_b,result_fx,select);

input [7:-8] valor_a,valor_b;
output reg [8:-8] result_fx;
input select;


always@ (valor_a or valor_b)
begin 
if (select==1)
result_fx = valor_a + valor_b;
else    
result_fx = valor_a - valor_b;
end

endmodule
```

Compiled in Quartus well. Then I launch Modelsim like this: **Tools > RTL simulation**. It launch Modelsim but it only gives me a lot of **zzzzzzzzzzzzz** in input and **xxxxxxxxxxxxxx** in output without anything in the wave.

I want to say that I'm not sure if I added this testbench correctly to the project. I'm a beginer. What I did was: **Assignments > Settings > Compile Test: click Test Benches > new**, looked for the file and add, and ok. I'm not sure that this is the correct way, because it looks too complex. Please help on this.

Also, I comment that I initiate the test bench writter template in quartus, but I ended changing everything from the file, final result is the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried your code on EDAPlayrgound (http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Cyc), and it looks fine to me. (You an give it a run for yourself, if you'd like).

You're seeing `X`'s because at time 0, you haven't specified values for any of your inputs (since you delay 10 timesteps before assigning anything). Consider either removing the first `#10`, or putting some assignments before it.

(`X` = Unknown Value; `Z` = High Impedance, which means neither a 1 nor a 0 input).

As for setting it up in Quartus, the way you did it was correct.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the meaning of the x and z, and for the website edaplayground, I already fixed it, problem is that module name has to be the same that the test-bench file name. I have to say the whole proceed of Quartus Test bench is generally complicated, Xilinx is much more intuitive.